# Find all words in container that start with a given character

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, containers

I need help with searching items in a container.

Ex: I have the following words in a container:

```
crr.push_back("fred");
crr.push_back("barney");
crr.push_back("pavel");
crr.push_back("zoot");
crr.push_back("jim");
crr.push_back("peter");
crr.push_back("patrick");
```

and I use this for finding:

```
const bool Contains(vector<char*>& Vec, char* Element)
{
    if (find(Vec.begin(), Vec.end(), Element) != Vec.end())
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    if (Contains(crr, "patrick"))
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Found\n");
    }
    else
    {
       system("cls");
       printf("Nah\n");
    }
}
```

It backs `Found` because `"patrick"` was found in the container, but I need to found all words, for example, which starts on `'p'`. For example, the output could be:

```
pavel
peter
patrick
```

How I can realise this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy all the words that begin with `'p'` into a `std::vector<std::string>` container and then display its contents. This can be done in linear time running, i.e., O(n). Space complexity is also linear, since you need a dedicated vector for storing every word that begins with `'p'`.

You can achieve this with the function template [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) by providing a suitable *predicate*, for example the following lambda `starts_with_p`:

```
// returns true whether the string starts with 'p', false otherwise
auto starts_with_p = [](std::string word) {
    if (word.front() == 'p')
        return true;
    return false;
};
```

Now, simply use `std::copy_if` with that predicate:

```
std::vector<std::string> matched_words;

std::copy_if(crr.begin(), crr.end(), 
             std::back_inserter(matched_words), starts_with_p);
```

The vector `matched_words` contains all the words from your original container that starts on `'p'`. You can now easily display them:

```
for (const auto& word: matched_words)
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
```

---

If you don't want linear space complexity but constant one, i.e., O(1), and your container `crr` supports *random access iterators*, you could first sort your collection `crr` with the [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function template and perform binary search on it by using [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) in order to get a subrange with all the words that start on `'p'`:

```
std::sort(crr.begin(), crr.end());

auto cmp_1st_char = [](std::string a, std::string b) {
    return a.front() < b.front();
};

auto p = std::equal_range(crr.begin(), crr.end(), "p", cmp_1st_char);

for (auto it = p.first; it != p.second; ++it)
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Note however that the running time complexity of sorting is O(n log n). So, with these two choices you face a trade-off between running time and space complexity.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this.Also it will work if i will type two or more symbols for exact my search?

Comment: @JoeDonson just write a suitable predicate that expresses your sorting criterion.